# Wrapped .exe with launch4j and jdk8 takes very long to start. Using jdk7 instead starts almost instant

Tags: java-8, launch4j

I have the following problem:

I used to have a launch4j config to create a wrapped executable from my runable jar using a bundeled jdk/jre7 for quite some time.

The Programm (launched with that .exe) starts almost immediatly with jdk7.
I now had to switch to jdk8 which results in a VERY slow startup. Everything works just fine, that is not the problem, but the launch process of that .exe takes ~1-2 Minutes and I simply don't get why.

Starting the application from within eclipse (using the same JDK8) it starts within seconds again (as it should!).

So... Any ideas what might cause this and how I can fix it?

Here is my current l4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>gui</headerType>
  <jar>C:\Users\user\workspace\DataUpdater\release\bin\DataUpdater-v2.6.1.jar</jar>
  <outfile>C:\Users\user\workspace\DataUpdater\release\DataUpdater.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle>DataUpdater: Kein kompatibles JRE gefunden</errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir>.</chdir>
  <priority>high</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl>https://www.google.de/</supportUrl>
  <stayAlive>true</stayAlive>
  <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon>C:\Users\user\workspace\DataUpdater\res\icons\DataUpdater.ico</icon>
  <singleInstance>
    <mutexName>DataUpdater v2.6.1</mutexName>
    <windowTitle>DataUpdater v2.6.1</windowTitle>
  </singleInstance>
  <jre>
    <path>./bundeled/jre1.8.0_92</path>
    <bundledJre64Bit>true</bundledJre64Bit>
    <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
    <minVersion>1.8.0</minVersion>
    <maxVersion>1.8.0_92</maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>jdkOnly</jdkPreference>
    <runtimeBits>64</runtimeBits>
    <initialHeapPercent>33</initialHeapPercent>
    <maxHeapPercent>80</maxHeapPercent>
    <opt>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</opt>
  </jre>
  <versionInfo>
    <fileVersion>2.6.1.0</fileVersion>
    <txtFileVersion>v2.6.1</txtFileVersion>
    <fileDescription>DataUpdater: Anwendung zum aktualisieren von -Datensätzen mittels externer Datenquellen wie Excel-Tabellen direkt auf Datenbankebene.</fileDescription>
    <copyright>Max Mustermann</copyright>
    <productVersion>2.6.1.0</productVersion>
    <txtProductVersion>v2.6.1</txtProductVersion>
    <productName>DataUpdater</productName>
    <companyName>Max Mustermann</companyName>
    <internalName>DataUpdater v2.6.1</internalName>
    <originalFilename>DataUpdater.exe</originalFilename>
  </versionInfo>
  <messages>
    <startupErr>DataUpdater konnte nicht gestartet werden. </startupErr>
    <bundledJreErr>DataUpdater erwartet ein bundled JRE. Dieses wurde nicht gefunden oder ist beschädigt.</bundledJreErr>
    <jreVersionErr>DataUpdater benötigt eine Java Laufzeitumgebung. Diese konnte nicht gefunden werden.
Bitte stellen Sie sicher, dass Java 8 auf Ihrem System installiert ist.</jreVersionErr>
    <launcherErr>Die Windows Registry verweist auf eine nicht mehr vorhandene oder beschädigte Java Installation.</launcherErr>
    <instanceAlreadyExistsMsg>DataUpdater wird bereits ausgeführt. 
Es ist immer nur eine DataUpdater-Instanz gleichzeitig erlaubt.</instanceAlreadyExistsMsg>
  </messages>
</launch4jConfig>
```

Edit:
The executable reacts the same on many different machines so it is not related to my local environment...

Additional Info:
I just noticed, that launching the application from the jar directly instead of the executable results in the same slow startup. 
So this MUST be related to the jdk8 somehow and not to l4j.
What I do not understand is why it starts so fast from within eclipse using the same jdk8.

Comment: Using a bundled (read: copied) JRE may inhibit the usage of the shared class data archive. Try to add the options `-Xshare:on -XX:+TraceClassPaths` to see whether this is the case.

Comment: Will give it a try as soon as I am back at home, thanks for the hint. Will keep you updated with the results!

Comment: Using those two additional parameters at start up does not make any difference (still takes ~30 seconds to start the jar and/or exe).

Comment: It wasn’t meant to improve the speed, but rather to give you log output about what’s going on, i.e. from where the classes are loaded.

Comment: Oh my bad. Where do i find these logs?

Comment: It’s written into the console when launched without wrapper, so you’ll have to look at launch4j’s documentation and your configuration to find out where that output gets redirected. But note that `-Xshare:on` *enforces* the use of the cache and make the start fail if the cahce doesn’t work instead of falling over to the slow startup, so if the option was passed to the JVM and the application started, it indicates that the cache was active. Still, looking at the log output may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research without any good result i noticed, that this "hang up" is not related to launch4j & Java 8 but related to log4j and Java 8.

Still not clear what excatly causes this but it is the topic of another question.

Comment: Did you ever found out what was going on?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, did not see your question. The answer is no, i did not found out what exactly was causing this behaviour, but I "solved" the issue by switching to JDK9 for that concrete project. Other projects use JDK11 and newer and also work fine.